# How to negate regex validation string?

Tags: regex, string, negate

I want to replace all the string except the @[anyword]

I have string like this:

`yng nnti dkasih tau :)"@mazayalinda: Yg klo ada cenel busana muslim aku mau ikutan dong "@noviwahyu10: Model ! Pasti gk blh klo k`

and the `@mazayalinda` and `@noviwahyu10` matches my regex `@\w*`.

However, I need to get rid all of the string, except for those 2 words above. We need to do the negation, but I am confuses about combining 2 regex, which are the regex to match the `@[anyword]` and the one to get rid all of the sentence except those 2 words.

Any ideas?

Comment: So use the NOT (`^`) operator?

Comment: its not working, i've changed into ^(@\w*) . i am testing using regexpal.com

Comment: What is the language?

Comment: @nhahtdh idk, i am using regexpal to test my regex

Comment: @nencor: The answer by FatalError works, since there is usually support for searching for all matches. You are just making thing hard for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

It's not completely clear from the context if this is a viable solution, but when you want to replace everything except a certain pattern it sounds more like you want a regex *search* rather than a replacement. For example, in python it might look like:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'yng nnti dkasih tau :)"@mazayalinda: Yg klo ada cenel busana muslim aku mau ikutan dong "@noviwahyu10: Model ! Pasti gk blh klo k'
>>> re.findall(r'@\w+', s)
['@mazayalinda', '@noviwahyu10']
```

Edit: in js, something like this would be more appropriate:

```
var s = 'yng nnti dkasih tau :)"@mazayalinda: Yg klo ada cenel busana muslim aku mau ikutan dong "@noviwahyu10: Model ! Pasti gk blh klo k';

// code from http://www.activestate.com/blog/2008/04/javascript-refindall-workalike
var rx = new RegExp("@\\w+", "g");
var matches = new Array();
while((match = rx.exec(s)) !== null){
    matches.push(match);
}
```

After this, `matches` contains all the matched strings. You can always join it back together if needed into a single string.

Comment: i am using regexpal.com to test my regex, sorry :(

Comment: @nencor: Is javascript regex your ultimate goal? Doing a search like this is certainly possible in js, though it does not look like that interface provides a way to test it.

Comment: yes perhaps, i need to get rid all of the string, so i can get the username and use them in yahoopipes :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you want to use capturing groups, not exactly negate the rest of the string, a regex like:

```
[^@]*(@\w+)[^@]*
```

Will capture those entries in capturing groups, and then, depending on your language, you can access each of the captured strings: http://rubular.com/r/qHKb35OK3g

Comment: I'm not sure if it's incorrect or not, if the user wants to get tweet handles, @@# isn't a valid one. Either way, it's just a matter of swapping `\w` for whatever needs to be in there.

Comment: The example is to show that, when the input contains garbage such as `@@#`, your regex will fail to remove the part in front.

Comment: that regex will select the entire string, i need to select !(@username) :(

Comment: @nencor: This is a trick so that you will retain the `@username` part in the resulting string. Otherwise, it will be hard (impossible?) to write a regex that match only the part without `@username`

Comment: yeah, its difficult to get rid all the string except the string which begins with @

Comment: My regex obtains the part you need, using capturing groups, it doesn't eliminate anything. It's a better approach, and you can use them in most languages, if not all.

Answer (score 0):

use this regex `(?<=^|@\w+\b)[^@]+` and union matches

Comment: Most regex engine doesn't have support for variable length look-behind.

Comment: `^|@\w+\b([^@]+)` and get marches from group

Comment: I think you mean this `(?:^|@\w+\b)([^@]+)`?

Comment: @nencor ^|@\w+\b([^@]+) it works, but may be you can't get match from group?

Comment: you almost got it, still, the string without `@` are included. we need to get rid all of the string except the string which started with `@` :(

Comment: look this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups.aspx first code block contain regex groups, you must repeate same matter

Comment: how do i do that ? can you show me any references, page, site that explain about that ?

Comment: what is your regex engine?

Comment: @burning iam using regexpal.com

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not entirely sure I understand the question, but if you want to keep just the names and use the rest just "to get rid of it", why don't you simply save the names and ignore the rest ?

If you're keen on matching the "non-name pattern" - this seems to be an excerpt from some kind of conversation, where every message starts with ':'. If so, then using this should simply do the trick.

:[^@]*

Answer (score -1):

You can use zero-width negative assertion, i.e., `@(?!mazayalinda|noviwahyu10)\w`.

This requires some sophisticated regular expression engine like Perl, Ruby, Java and so on.
If you have classic engine, the way as @pcalcao sais is best.

Comment: Now you need to match the usernames and use it to construct a regex, which is round-about way to do the task. -1

Comment: the username isn't always be `@mazayalinda` or `@noviwahyu10` :(

Comment: sorry, I completely misread your question.  how about `(?:^|\s)(?:[^@]\S*|@\W\S+)(?=\s|$)`?